# mongodb dispaly only particular values from a list

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I have a list of dates and I am doing a `$regex` to find those values but I want to display only the queried values.

The data stored in the collection:

```
{
    "Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
    "Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766",
    "Booked" : [
            "1-10-2015",
            "6-10-2015",
            "11-12-2015",
            "16-12-2015",
            "10-12-2015"
    ],
    "Vid" : "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9"
}
```

I do the search like this

```
db.calendar2.find({"Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854","Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766","Booked" : {"$regex": "10-2015"}})
```

from my python program.

the output i got.

```
{
    "Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
    "Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766",
    "Booked" : [
            "1-10-2015",
            "6-10-2015",
            "11-12-2015",
            "16-12-2015",
            "10-12-2015"
    ],
    "Vid" : "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9"
}
```

desired output

```
{
    "Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
    "Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766",
    "Booked" : [
            "1-10-2015",
            "6-10-2015"
    ],
    "Vid" : "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9"
}
```

Can anyone guide me

**Edit**
 i already tried that but i did not get the output,i want only the particular set of dates which match the regex condition  to display

Comment: sorry my mistake missed `{}`, I am new SO i will accept from now on

Comment: @user3100115 I already tried that but it did not give me the desired output. I am unable to display only the values which have the substring `10-2015`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can achieve what you want using the aggregation framework:

-Unwind the Booked array

-Match the document you want (and the array elements that have been unwinded)

-Group the results back together by your filter and push the unwinded array elements back into Booked

-Project the results to unpack the values from the group object

```
db.calendar2.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$Booked"
}, {
    $match: {
        "Pid": "5652f92761be0b14889d9854",
        "Registration": "TN 56 HD 6766",
        "Vid": "56543ed261be0b0a60a896c9",
        "Booked": /10-2015/
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            Pid: "$Pid",
            Registration: "$Registration",
            Vid: "$Vid"
        },
        Booked: {
            $push: "$Booked"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        Pid: "$_id.Pid",
        Registration: "$_id.Registration",
        Vid: "$_id.Vid",
        Booked: 1,
        _id: 0
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you.its working well in mongodb.how can i run in python code?

Comment: thank you.its working well in mongodb terminal,how can i run the code in python

Comment: Should be quite similar to the above https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/python/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

When you find in MongoDB you ask for documents with certain conditions. Find returns you this documents. But you can "project" to only get certain fields. Its the second parameter of the [find method](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

I think that in this case you can  do:

```
db.calendar2.find({"Pid" : "5652f92761be0b14889d9854","Registration" : "TN 56 HD 6766","Booked" : /10-2015/ }, {"Booked.$": /10-2015/ } )
```

Using the [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) and // instead of $regex (its the same).

It works that way?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm checking that the $ operator only gets the first element of the array that matches the query.